# Spring Security Authenication Failed wrapped by JBOSS to html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jboss

I have Spring Security in Spring Boot application that runs on Jboss server.

I configured login filter extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. It has attepmptAuthentication method as below:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info("attemptAuthentication");
    AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
    Authentication authentication = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(),
            credentials.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList()));
    log.info("authentication: " + authentication);
    return authentication;
}
```

When authenticate on AuthenticationManager fails, then it throws AuthenticationException.

Then this exception is put into response by SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler with

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
```

When I run this application locally using Spring Boot and embedded tomcat server, this is translated to JSON response.

But when I run it on JBOSS, it is translated to different response, and to HTML page with error message:

[image: jboss error]

How to make it work the same as on local configuration?